# efficiently search newer revision file?

Tags: algorithm

1. My program loop over every file in a folder to check whether it's outdated or latest revision drawing.
2. the format of drawing filename is in **"VALID-FILE-PATTERN-AAA-R1.pdf"**.
3. The drawing file is considered **outdated** if **"VALID-FILE-PATTERN-AAA-R2.pdf"** file exsits.
4. Sometimes, Revision #2 file doesn't exist and directly goes from R1 to R3 leaving out the R2.

My question is "***what is the more efficient way to check latest revision drawing?***"

What I'm planning is like this code

```
if(nextRevisionExists()) {
    doSomethingWithOldRevision(drawingFile);
} else {
    // MAXIMUM REVISION IS 150 TO PREVENT TOO MUCH LOAD
    for(int i=currentRevision + 2; i <= 150; i++) {             
        if(revisionExists(i)) 
            doSomethingWithOldRevision(drawingFile);
    }
}
```

I'm not a professional programmer but just document controller. please understand my poor English & insufficient programming knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More efficient way would be to store map of file name to revision number and update revision number while iterating through the files:

```
//std::string contains VALID-FILE-PATTERN-AAA
// int contains revision  number for that file.
    std::map<std::string,int> revisionMap;
```

You will need to iterate through list of files in the folder ONCE to generate the map, map is self sufficient in a way it gives you full list of files in a folder with latest revision for each file (as you generate the map, you only memorize latest revision for each file).

Answer (score 1):

Use the following pseudo code,

```
create a map with key being filename and value being revision
do for each file{
    Parse the file name and extract file name and revision
    if the map already has the key as file name{
        get its value from map, compare with current file's revision
    }
    else{
        add the key value pair(name,revision) to the map
    }
}
```